# How can I get all data from BindableLayout ItemsSource onclick events

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, listviewitem

I am trying to create a sales app using Xamarin forms but am stuck on adding products to cart. I am using BindableLayout ItemsSource to populate my list horizontally:

```xml
 <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding NafakaList}" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20"
                 VerticalOptions="Start">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="nafakaStackLayout">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Frame Padding="0" HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
                           CornerRadius="10" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    </Frame>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" x:Name="nameView" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Price}" x:Name="Price" Margin="0,-7,0,0" TextColor="#62153B"
                                   FontSize="12" FontFamily="{StaticResource BoldFont}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                            <!--this is the button that I am using to pass data through-->
                            <Button Command="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="White" CommandParameter="{Binding Product}"
                                    HeightRequest="35" FontSize="Small" Text="Add to Cart" x:Name="cartAdd"
                                    Clicked="cartAdd_Clicked" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
```

This is my list and button click event:

```cs
public void cartAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Object commandParameter = ((Button) sender).CommandParameter;

    pr = (Product) NafakaList.GetItem(1);

    DisplayAlert(pr.Name, "test", "Ok");
}
```

List:

```cs
public List<Product> NafakaList { get => GetProduct(); }

private List<Product> GetProduct(string name)
{
    var products = new List<Product>();

    products.Add(new Product {ID= 1, Image = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568347355280-d33fdf77d42a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80", Name = "Mchele", Price = "2500 tsh" });
    products.Add(new Product { ID = 2, Image = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574323347407-f5e1ad6d020b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=680&q=80", Name = "Ngano", Price = "1600 tsh" }); ;
    products.Add(new Product { ID = 3, Image = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579705745811-a32bef7856a3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80", Name = "Maharage", Price = "1500 tsh" });
    products.Add(new Product { ID = 4, Image = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560705185-d0291220a442?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=667&q=80", Name = "Kunde", Price = "1000 tsh" });
    return products;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Code also

```cs
public void cartAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var item = sender as Button;
   var data = item.BindingContext as Product;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bind `Command` or `CommandParameter` in your code:

```xml
<Button Clicked="cartAdd_Clicked" ... />
```

Use the `BindingContext` to get the `Product`:

```cs
public void cartAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var product = (Product)((Button)sender).BindingContext;

   ...
}
```